# Trouble With Multithreading in RPi Pico (Need to toggle an LED on one thread and run a rotary menu connected to LCD on other thread)

Tags: multithreading, rotation, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

```
import machine
import utime
import _thread
from rotary_encoder_classes import *

clock_pin = machine.Pin(25, machine.Pin.OUT)
frequency = 1

def clock(frequency):
    while True:
        clock_pin.value(1)            #Set led turn on
        utime.sleep(1/(frequency*2))
        clock_pin.value(0)            #Set led turn off
        utime.sleep(1/(frequency*2))

#clock runs in second core
_thread.start_new_thread(clock, [frequency])

#main menu
pointer = 0
main_menu_options = ["> Clock Frequency", "> IC Tester", "> Voltmeter"]

#lcd
from pico_i2c_lcd import I2cLcd
i2c = machine.I2C(0, sda=machine.Pin(0), scl=machine.Pin(1), freq=400000)
I2C_ADDR = i2c.scan()[0]
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, I2C_ADDR, 2, 16)
lcd.putstr(main_menu_options[pointer])

#rotary encoder
last_Enc_Counter_1 = 0
Enc_Counter_1 = 0
Last_Qtr_Cntr_1 = 0
Qtr_Cntr_1 = 0
error_1 = 0

last_Enc_Counter_2 = 0
Enc_Counter_2 = 0
Last_Qtr_Cntr_2 = 0
Qtr_Cntr_2 = 0
error_2 = 0

#switch
Enc_1 = R_Encoder(15, 14)
Enc_1.DisplayPins()
Enc_1.Reset_Counter()

#shaft encoder
Enc_2 = R_Encoder(12, 11)
Enc_2.DisplayPins()
Enc_2.Reset_Counter()

Enc_1_SW = machine.Pin(13, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
Enc_1_SW_State = "UP"

#main code
while True:
    utime.sleep(.01)
    
    Qtr_Cntr_1 = round(Enc_1.Enc_Counter/4)
    if Qtr_Cntr_1 != Last_Qtr_Cntr_1:
        print(Qtr_Cntr_1)
        last_Enc_Counter_1 = Enc_1.Enc_Counter
        Last_Qtr_Cntr_1 = Qtr_Cntr_1
        
    if (Enc_1_SW.value() == True) and (Enc_1_SW_State == "DOWN"):
        Enc_1_SW_State = "UP"
        print("Switch is UP")
    elif (Enc_1_SW.value() == False) and (Enc_1_SW_State == "UP"):
        Enc_1_SW_State = "DOWN"
        print("Switch is DOWN")
        
    Qtr_Cntr_2 = round(Enc_2.Enc_Counter/4)
    if Qtr_Cntr_2 != Last_Qtr_Cntr_2:
        print(Qtr_Cntr_1, Qtr_Cntr_2)
        last_Enc_Counter_2 = Enc_2.Enc_Counter
        Last_Qtr_Cntr_2 = Qtr_Cntr_2
```

When I run this code, the LED toggles, but the moment I turn the rotary encoder, the LED stops and the encoder does not produce an output either. The codes for rotary encoder, LCD and LED work separately but I'm not able to combine them, so I think the problem is with threading.

All the extra files that I've used are available here: https://github.com/riyasach189/Smart-Trainer-Kit

Comment: For rotary encoder reading I would go with interupts and not separate thread.

Comment: Lixas:  He is using interrupts to read the encoder.  The only thing the second core does is blink the LED.  OP: After you turn the rotary encoder and the LED stops blinking, do you know whether your main code is still running?  How about you blink and LED in the main code so you can determine whether that loop is running, or if your main code got stuck in an infinite loop.